# Truncate a time duration by minutes

Tags: go, time

I want to subtract 30 minutes from `orderDeliveryStartTime` by using the `Truncate` function of the `time` library in Go. But it's subtracting 30 seconds instead. How can I subtract exactly 30 minutes from a `time.Time`?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var pickingTimeConfig int
    pickingTimeConfig = 30

    layoutTime := "2006-01-02 15:04:05"

    pickingTime := time.Duration(pickingTimeConfig) * time.Minute
    fmt.Println(pickingTime.Nanoseconds())
    vcmTimeLocation := time.FixedZone("UTC+7", 25200)

    orderDeliveryStartTime := time.Date(2019, 4, 11, 13, 0, 30, 0, vcmTimeLocation)

    fmt.Println(orderDeliveryStartTime.Format(layoutTime))
    fmt.Println(orderDeliveryStartTime.Truncate(pickingTime).Format(layoutTime))

}
```

Actual Result:

> 1800000000000
>
> 2019-04-11 13:00:30
>
> 2019-04-11 13:00:00

Expected Result:

> 1800000000000
>
> 2019-04-11 13:00:30
>
> 2019-04-11 12:30:30

Comment: You want to subtract 30 minutes from a timestamp? Then simply add `-30 minutes` to it, e.g. `t2 := t1.Add(-30 * time.Minute)`. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: [Truncate](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate) is not for subtracting but for rounding down. If you want to *subtract* follow icza's comment. If you want to *truncate* your expected result is incorrect.

Comment: I tried `sub` func but it throws an error `cannot use -30 * time.Minute (type time.Duration) as type time.Time in argument to ...`

Comment: You have to use the `Time.Add()` method, not `Time.Sub()`. I provided the code in my comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the [`Time.Add()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Add) method, passing `-30 * time.Minute`:

```
t2 := orderDeliveryStartTime.Add(-30 * time.Minute)
fmt.Println(t2.Format(layoutTime))
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QGZl3xxoeCD)):

```
2019-04-11 13:00:30
2019-04-11 12:30:30
```